# Dot product of a vector and del operator

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, vectors

How did this expansion come about.
[image]

What is the physical significance of this expansion.

And what is the significance of 
$$\vec{A} . \nabla {\vec{A}}$$
And what does this mathematically represent.

Comment: $\vec A \cdot \nabla = A_x \partial_x + A_y \partial_y + A_z \partial_z$ and $(\vec A \cdot \nabla) \vec B = ( (\vec A \cdot \nabla) B_x, (\vec A \cdot \nabla) B_y, (\vec A \cdot \nabla) B_z )$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\newcommand{\col}[3]{\left(\begin{matrix} #1 \\ #2 \\ #3 \end{matrix}\right)}$
$\newcommand{\vecc}[1]{\col{#1_x}{#1_y}{#1_z}}$
$$
\vec A \times (\nabla \times \vec A)
= \vecc A \times \left( \vecc \partial \times \vecc A \right)
= \vecc A \times \col{\partial_y A_z - \partial_z A_y}{\partial_z A_x - \partial_x A_z}{\partial_x A_y - \partial_y A_x} \\
= \col
{A_y(\partial_x A_y - \partial_y A_x) - A_z(\partial_z A_x - \partial_x A_z)}
{A_z(\partial_y A_z - \partial_z A_y) - A_x(\partial_x A_y - \partial_y A_x)}
{A_x(\partial_z A_x - \partial_x A_z) - A_y(\partial_y A_z - \partial_z A_y)}
= \col
{(A_y \partial_x A_y + A_z \partial_x A_z) - (A_y \partial_y + A_z \partial_z) A_x}
{(A_z \partial_y A_z + A_x \partial_y A_x) - (A_z \partial_z + A_x \partial_x) A_y}
{(A_x \partial_z A_x + A_y \partial_z A_y) - (A_x \partial_x + A_y \partial_y) A_z} \\
= \col
{(A_x \partial_x A_x + A_y \partial_x A_y + A_z \partial_x A_z) - (A_x \partial_x + A_y \partial_y + A_z \partial_z) A_x}
{(A_x \partial_y A_x + A_y \partial_y A_y + A_z \partial_y A_z) - (A_x \partial_x + A_y \partial_y + A_z \partial_z) A_y}
{(A_x \partial_z A_x + A_y \partial_z A_y + A_z \partial_z A_z) - (A_x \partial_x + A_y \partial_y + A_z \partial_z) A_z}
= \col
{\vec A \cdot \partial_x \vec A - (\vec A \cdot \nabla) A_x}
{\vec A \cdot \partial_y \vec A - (\vec A \cdot \nabla) A_y}
{\vec A \cdot \partial_z \vec A - (\vec A \cdot \nabla) A_z}
= \col
{\frac12 \partial_x (\vec A \cdot \vec A)}
{\frac12 \partial_y (\vec A \cdot \vec A)}
{\frac12 \partial_z (\vec A \cdot \vec A)}
- \col
{(\vec A \cdot \nabla) A_x}
{(\vec A \cdot \nabla) A_y}
{(\vec A \cdot \nabla) A_z}
\\
= \frac12 \nabla (\vec A \cdot \vec A) - (\vec A \cdot \nabla) \vec A
$$

Thus,
$$(\vec A \cdot \nabla) \vec A = \frac12 \nabla (\vec A \cdot \vec A) - \vec A \times (\nabla \times \vec A)$$

Comment: What's the physical significance of $$\vec{A} \times (\nabla \times \vec{A})$$. ie. Cross product of a vector and it's curl?

Comment: Actually I don't know. If you provide more context perhaps I can understand its physical significance.

Comment: It is related to the Gromeka lamb form of Navier Stokes Equation.

Comment: I can answer what is the physical significance of $(\vec A \cdot \nabla) \vec A$ when $\vec A$ is the velocity of a fluid. 

A particle that moves with the fluid in some kind of field $\phi(\vec x, t)$ will notice a time derivative of this field that is
$$\frac{D}{Dt} \phi = \left( \frac{\partial}{\partial t} + \vec A \cdot \nabla \right) \phi$$
Therefore $(\vec A \cdot \nabla) \vec A$ will be the time derivative of the velocity of the fluid noticed by a particle that moves with the fluid in a static flow (i.e. $\frac{\partial}{\partial t} \vec A = \vec 0$).

Comment: Such a particle could be a small element of the fluid itself.

Comment: Ie, in steady state, the material derevative $$\dfrac{D \phi}{D t}$$ would become $$\vec{A} \cdot \nabla \phi$$, ie, the convective acceleration.

Comment: That is correct.